# Java/Scala: How to find available ubuntu system fonts which can render less common unicode

Tags: java, ubuntu, unicode, fonts, libreoffice

I am writing a java/scala program which generates pdf files for various different languages (like Chinese, Persian, Tamil). I am using itext.

The workflow is that I copy and paste some foreign language text into a UI I've built, click "Generate", then it creates and saves a nicely formatted pdf with that text inside.

My program is expandable in that more languages can be added (currently supporting about 8), but that requires adding more fonts, and manually downloading and testing new fonts is quite time consuming and doesn't scale well. Plus it's hard to know if a font supports *all* the characters (e.g. for Chinese) and I'm not going to visually notice if the odd character gets dropped out.

What would be nice is if my app could search my system for existing fonts which can render that text. This app is only going to be run on my computer so I'm not concerned about portability issues.

For example, libreoffice has no troubles rendering Chinese and Persian. Is it possible to find and reuse whatever fonts libreoffice uses? Or my browser? Libreoffice itself seems to use some kind of automatic font redirection for if I paste in some Chinese while the font is say Liberation Serif, it still manages to render the Chinese. I also prefer the Libreoffice fonts to the free ones I find on the internet. It's looks professional and I trust it more.

I haven't been able to find any good documentation explaining how Ubuntu and/or Libreoffice is magically handling this and I don't know of a good tool for searching my system for existing fonts that are able to render certain code points. Ubuntu has a Font Viewer program but it's not searchable by code point.

I am using 14.04 LTS and itext 5.0.6. Scala or Java code snippets are fine.

Thanks in advance!

-Rohan

Comment: "How do I....?" questions without any kind of code to show what you've tried so far isn't really what SO is for. This feels very much like a question that you should first hit up the wider internet for, googling for "how to detect system-installed fonts using Java", and then just *trying things* to see how far you get. Then, when you have code you think really ought to work, but doesn't, and you can't figure out why even after googling for solutions, then that'd be the right time to post a question here, with code, and explanations on what you think it should do and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up building a utility which recursively searches a directory of fonts for those which can render a piece of text. (The crucial method is `font.canDisplay(Char)`)

On Ubuntu a good directory to target is `/usr/share/fonts/truetype`.

Of the fonts found, my utility would render the text with that font so that I could see which fonts I preferred the look of (and could then pick one through a UI).

To find all the fonts in a particular directory I used code something like this (I've removed UI code to make it more like a script):

```
val rootFontsDir = {
  val fontsDirPath = "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/" // Customise this
  val dir = new File(fontsDirPath)
  if (!dir.exists())
    throw new RuntimeException(s"Nothing found at path: '$fontsDirPath'")
  if (!dir.isDirectory)
    throw new RuntimeException(s"Object at path: '$fontsDirPath' isn't a directory")
  dir
}

def findFontFilesInDir(dir: File): Seq[File] = {
  val files = dir.listFiles()
  val subDirs = files.filter(_.isDirectory)
  val fontFiles = files.filter(_.isFile).filter(_.getName.endsWith(".ttf"))

  val subDirFontFiles = subDirs.flatMap(findFontFilesInDir)

  subDirFontFiles ++ fontFiles
}

case class FontInfo(font: Font, file: File)

val allFontInfo = findFontFilesInDir(rootFontsDir).map {
  case fontFile => FontInfo(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, fontFile), fontFile)
}
```

Once you have `allFontInfo` you can search for fonts that can render some text quite easily:

```
val sampleText = "尺度衡量人"

val matchingFontInfo = allFontInfo.filter(fontInfo => sampleText.forall(char => fontInfo.font.canDisplay(char)))
```

Then just loop over the results to see what the fonts are:

```
matchingFontInfo.foreach {
  case FontInfo(font, file) =>
    println(s"Text: '$sampleText' can be rendered by font '${font.getFontName}' found at '${file.getPath}'")
}
```

Or if you want to actually see it rendered so that you can compare visually:

```
matchingFontInfo.zipWithIndex.map {
  case (FontInfo(baseFont, file), index) =>
    val largerFont = baseFont.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 24)
    val label = new JLabel(s"[$index] ${baseFont.getFontName} : ${sampleText} (${file.getPath})")
    label.setFont(largerFont)
    // Add the label into a UI component ...
}
```

In my code the sample text was fed in through a UI rather than being hard coded as above and I spat out all the labels into a `JFrame`.